# "It is likely you do not have the permissions" when trying to launch the development server for WebAssembly + Vite + Vue

Tags: vue.js, rust, webassembly, vite, rust-wasm

When I run `yarn dev` I get the following output:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
warning package.json: No license field
$ vite


⚡️⚡️         Hello RSW!           ⚡️⚡️
⚡️⚡️  Vite + Rust  WebAssembly  ⚡️⚡️

vite-plugin-rsw (1.8.0)
[rsw::deploy] https://github.com/lencx/rsw-node

[rsw::optimized] wasm-pack build wasm.

up to date, audited 241 packages in 3s

7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

4 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../../../home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/wasm/pkg
npm ERR! dest /usr/lib/node_modules/wasm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../../../home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/wasm/pkg' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/wasm'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../../../home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/wasm/pkg' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/wasm'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../../../home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/wasm/pkg',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/wasm'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/isaachmi/.npm/_logs/2021-07-21T14_44_01_966Z-debug.log

[rsw::npm::link]
  ↳ wasm   /home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/wasm/pkg 

error when starting dev server:
Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:

  wasm (imported by /home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Are they installed?
    at optimizeDeps (/home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f2b4ca46.js:73091:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOptimize (/home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f2b4ca46.js:73765:48)
    at async Server.httpServer.listen (/home/isaachmi/projects/my-blackspace/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f2b4ca46.js:73779:17)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

My WebAssembly package is called `wasm` and this is my vite configuration:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import ViteRsw from "vite-plugin-rsw";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    ViteRsw({
      crates: ["wasm"],
    }),
  ],
});
```

I'm using a [plugin](https://github.com/lencx/vite-plugin-rsw) for vite to use Rust and WebAssembly. I followed the example that they have with Vue3 but using my package. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I noticed that by running it with `sudo` I was able to run the program, but is there a way to give those permissions for my user?

Comment: Looks like its trying to install wasm globally on your machine, and of course failing to do so.

Comment: and what can I do? I tried to give me the permissions of the files and folders and yarn can launch the server but rust don't compile

Comment: What are the permission bits of those two files? `ls -l <file>` Have you tried changing the permission mode with `chmod +x` or `chown`?

Comment: for the vite file is `.rw-r--r--` and for the wasm directory is `drwxr-xr-x`. And yes I tried and with that I can run the server with vite, but I can't compile rust yet. When I enter to the server it throws me this error: `13:11:10 [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "wasm" from "src/components/HelloWorld.vue". Does the file exist?`

Comment: Look like a simple path / module issue. Also if this is a different issue it might be worth editing this post or starting a new one.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try to solve it, if I can't maybe I will create a new one, thanks